# What is the difference between a + 1 and a - 1 +2 in javascript

Tags: javascript, operators

I got a project and found very mysterious one.
I found `a - 1 + 2` in javascript code and I thought it will same as `a + 1` and replaced with it.
But it is making wrong answer.
when

```
a = 1 => a -1 +2 = 2
      => a + 1 = 11
```

Can anyone describe about this issue?

Comment: `a` is a string...

Comment: It is an html input object, how can I set html object contain only integers?

Comment: You can use `+a + 1` to make sure `a` is coerced to a number. JavaScript has several ways to convert a string to a number.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`a` is a string. Because + can mean addition *or string concatenation*, that's what you're seeing here. In JavaScript, if you have at least one addend that is a string, both operands are coerced to strings and concatenated. Thus `"1" + 1` is `"11"`. But in JavaScript, - only has one meaning, subtraction. Thus it converts both operands to numbers and subtracts. No concatenation occurs with subtraction, hence the difference.

Just coerce `a` into an integer before adding:

```
+a + 1
```

Here, the unary `+` implicitly converts `a` to a number.

Comment: Thanks, I got a solution.